# Merging collection arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, underscore.js, lodash

I'm looking for a way to take this array.

```
[
  {
    "alpha": ['a', 'b', 'c'],
    "beta": ['d', 'e', 'f'] 
  },
  {
    "alpha": ['h', 'i', 'j'],
    "beta": ['k', 'l', 'm']  
  }
]
```

And transform it into this object.

```
{
  "alpha": ['a', 'b', 'c', 'h', 'i', 'j']
  "beta": ['d', 'e', 'f', 'k', 'l', 'm']  
}
```

Preferably using lodash or underscore. What's the best way to do this?

Comment: what do you mean by "best"? in terms of what? speed or resource consumption?

Comment: @Raptor Simplicity, api, spec.

Comment: In general terms, you have an array of objects, where each object has identical keys but unique values. you want to concat the values belonging to the same keys?

Comment: Why do you use underscore js for this?

Comment: @eugensunic I don't understand why I wouldn't.

Comment: Have a look at the [merge example](https://lodash.com/docs#merge) in the lodash documentation. The example does something very similar to what you want to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go this way:

```
var or = [
  {
    "alpha": ['a', 'b', 'c'],
    "beta": ['d', 'e', 'f'] 
  },
  {
    "alpha": ['h', 'i', 'j'],
    "beta": ['k', 'l', 'm']  
  }
];

var res = {
    "alpha": _.union(or[0].alpha, or[1].alpha)
    "beta": _.union(or[0].beta, or[1].beta)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have the spec array and objects, do this:

```js
var arr = [
    {
        "alpha": ['a', 'b', 'c'],
        "beta": ['d', 'e', 'f']
    },
    {
        "alpha": ['h', 'i', 'j'],
        "beta": ['k', 'l', 'm']
    }
];

var obj = new Object();

arr.forEach(function(el) {
    for (key in el) {
        if (el.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            if (!obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                obj[key] = [];
            }
            obj[key] = obj[key].concat(el[key]);
        }
    }
});

console.log(obj);
```

Answer (score 1):

a simple way of doing this is using the `concat` method on an array like so:

```
var array = [
  {
    "alpha": ['a', 'b', 'c'],
    "beta": ['d', 'e', 'f'] 
  },
  {
    "alpha": ['h', 'i', 'j'],
    "beta": ['k', 'l', 'm']  
  }
]

var mergedAlphaArray = array[0].alpha.concat(array[1].alpha);
var mergedBetaArray = array[0].beta.concat(array[1].beta);
```

this will merge the two arrays into one.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I came up with using underscore.

```
var sets = [
  {
    "alpha": ['a', 'b', 'c'],
    "beta": ['d', 'e', 'f'] 
  },
  {
    "alpha": ['h', 'i', 'j'],
    "beta": ['k', 'l', 'm']  
  }
]

var full = _.mapObject(sets[0], function (set, key) {
  var result =  _.chain(sets)
  .map(function(set){
    return _.chain(set)
    .pick(key)
    .values()
    .value()
  })
  .value()
  return _.flatten(result)
})

console.log(full)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here it is, genaric solution and works for dynamic array length.

```
var arr = [
    {
        "alpha": ['a', 'b', 'c'],
        "beta": ['d', 'e', 'f']
    },
    {
        "alpha": ['h', 'i', 'j'],
        "beta": ['k', 'l', 'm']
    }
];

 function merge(data) {
  var alphaArr = [],
      betaArr = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
      Array.prototype.push.apply(alphaArr, arr[i].alpha);
      Array.prototype.push.apply(betaArr, arr[i].beta);
  }
  return {
      "alpha": alphaArr,
      "beta": betaArr
     }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you look for a jQuery version...

```
var finals = [];
$.each(test, function(k, v) {
    $.each(v, function(key, val) {
        if(finals[key] == undefined) {
            finals[key] = val;
        } else {
            finals[key] = finals[key].concat(val);
        }
    });
});
console.log(finals);
```

This does not specify the name of array keys, which give flexibility.

Working Demo: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zq4724j1/)